# Comment URL Title Auto Path for other channel

Tags: ee2, url, url-title

I've run into a bit of an issue when working on a video archive site for a church. I currently have sermon series in a channel and then services in another channel that is tied to the series channel by a relationship field. I want to be able to feature a single week's service on the homepage, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the service's URL to point to the series  URL. The site is here: [video.lifebridgechurch.com](http://video.lifebridgechurch.com). On the homepage, I have the featured post which is using Comment URL Title Auto Path to generate the URL. However, I need the last segment of the URL to be the series URL instead of the service title since I don't have a template for just a single service. If you go to the full archives and click on a series, all of the services are shown in tabs so they don't need their own template.

I've tried MX Title Control but I can't seem to get it to do what I need.

Hopefully this makes sense! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series is the parent that you are linking to, you can just use the relationship's [parent tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#id15)

Then you could simply pull the url_title of the parent entry.